# Make Chapter-Title "hanging", intend after Line-Break

Tags: chapters, titles, indentation

So I'm using the report class and I need to modify the chapter titles. This is what i got so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}         
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\definecolor{Titel}{RGB}{0,0,144} 
\makeatletter                       
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
 \vspace*{-10\p@}%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge\bfseries  \textcolor{Titel}{\thechapter.\quad #1}
    \vskip 20\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{A very longus chongus chapter Titel}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is what i need (the same as for section-titles):

[image]

And i really can't figure out how to make it!?
Using the titlesec package with \titleformat gives me the error "Entered in Horizontal mode" and i can't modify other important parameters as making it appear a bit higher up on the page. This is why I would like to redefine the argument.

Answer (score 1):

You have the `\titlespacing` command in `titlesec`. I used the short notation `*n` which means a vertical spacing of ‘n ex’, with a possible automatic small stretchability and shrinkability. The default format is the  `hangstyle`.

Here is a possible code, with values to be adjusted to your needs:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{Titel}{RGB}{0,0,144}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\Huge\bfseries\filright\color{Titel}}{\thechapter.}{0.5em}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{*-4}{*4}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A very longus chongus chapter Titel}

\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is something you can easily achieve with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}         
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\definecolor{Titel}{RGB}{0,0,144} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\filright\Huge
   \bfseries\color{Titel}}
  {\thechapter.}
  {5mm}
  {}
  []
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-3cm}{1cm}
\begin{document}
 \chapter{A very longus chongus chapter that fits in more than one line}
 \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If for some reason you don't want to use `titlesec`, this is an adaptation of your code:

```
\makeatletter                       
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
 \vspace*{-10\p@}%
 {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
  \interlinepenalty\@M
  \color{Titel}
  \hangindent=1.5cm
  \Huge\bfseries\makebox[1.5cm][l]{\thechapter.\quad}#1
  \vskip 20\p@
}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Its more better to use `\@hangfrom` instead of manual value by using `\hangindent`